# How can I get Emacs' key bindings in Python's IDLE?

Tags: python, emacs, ide, keyboard

I use Emacs primarily for coding Python but sometimes I use IDLE. Is there a way to change the key bindings easily in IDLE to match Emacs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IDLE provides Emacs keybindings without having to install other software.

1. Open up the menu item Options -> Configure IDLE...
2. Go to Keys tab
3. In the drop down menu on the right
   side of the dialog change the select
   to "IDLE Classic Unix"

It's not the true emacs key bindings but you get the basics like movement, saving/opening, ...

Answer (score 2):

There's a program for Windows called `XKeymacs` that allows you to specify emacs keybindings for different programs.  It should work with IDLE.

http://www.cam.hi-ho.ne.jp/oishi/indexen.html

-Mark

Answer (score 0):

['readline' module](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5/lib/module-readline.html) supposedly provides Emacs like key bindings and even functionality. However, it is not available on Windows but on Unix. Therefore, this might be a viable solution if you are not using Windows.

```
import readline
```

Since I am running IDLE on Windows it is unfortunately not an option for me.